# Graph with more than six vertices of odd degree cannot be decomposed into three paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Im trying to solve the following question: Is it true that a graph with more than six vertices of odd degree cannot be decomposed into three paths?

I was wondering if my reasoning was correct in trying to solve this question? I assume that we are dealing with a finite graph as an infinite graph would contain an infinite path and I'm not sure that the reasoning holds in this case. Here is what I have so far:

If we wish to decompose a graph into three paths then for each path we must travel through some sequence of vertices $v_1,v_2,...,v_k$ in succession. The final vertex in this path must be of odd degree as we are dealing with a finite path. This means that we require three vertices of odd degree for the endpoints. In addition for each starting point our vertex will be a vertex of odd degree as this refers to the start of the path in each of the three paths. We thus require a total of $6$ vertices of odd degree. Since we are given a graph with more than six vertices of odd degree it is not possible to construct a decomposition into three separate paths.

Answer (score 1):

> If we wish to decompose a graph into three paths then for each path we must travel through some sequence of vertices v1,v2,...,vk in succession.

Sounds good.

> The final vertex in this path must be of odd degree as we are dealing with a finite path.

not necessarily, for example a triangle graph $C_3$ can be decomposed into $3$ paths of length $1$ and it has only even degree vertices.

> This means that we require three vertices of odd degree for the endpoints.

again this is false, but it seems to be going against what we want to prove since our graph already has more than $6$ vertices of odd degree.

> In addition for each starting point our vertex will be a vertex of odd degree as this refers to the start of the path in each of the three paths.

what is our vertex?

> We thus require a total of 6 vertices of odd degree.

We "require" a total of $6$ vertices of odd degree?

> Since we are given a graph with more than six vertices of odd degree it is not possible to construct a decomposition into three separate paths.

this last part looks good, although it's simply repeating the thing we wish to prove.

---

I think it's easier to just assume a graph $G$ can be decomposed into three paths, and note that every vertex of odd degree in $G$ must be an endpoint of at least one path, therefore there are at most $6$ vertices of odd degree in $G$.